# plot two different data frames, grouped by one or more variables, with different labels in the legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Consider the following sample data frames:

```
x1=seq(2,7,length.out=13)
y1a=1.5*x1+4; y2a=1.5*x1+7;y3a=1.5*x1+9;
X1=rep(x1,3)
Y1=c(y1a,y2a,y3a)
groups1=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=13)
df1=data.frame(groups1,X1,Y1)

x2=seq(4,10,length=10)
y1b=3*x2+4; y2b=3*x2+7;y3b=3*x2+9;
X2=rep(x2,3)
Y2=c(y1b,y2b,y3b)
groups2=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=10)
df2=data.frame(groups2,X2,Y2)
```

Plotting them with `ggplot2`, I get an automatic legend, which is great. However, the legend is the same for both dataframes, which is not so great:

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_line(data=df1,aes(x=X1, y=Y1, color = groups1)) +
     geom_point(data=df2,aes(x=X2, y=Y2, color = groups2))
```

[image]

Instead, I would like the legend to distinguish between curves coming from `df1`, and curves coming from `df2`, labeling the former ones "Pred" and the latter "Test". How can I do that? Note that the real data frames are much larger and very different (one has ~ 400 rows x 10 columns, and the other has ~90 rows x 30 columns), thus merging them together wouldn't be simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy alternative is to use a different shape for the points for which you can use a `fill` and set the `color` to `NA` (thus getting the same result as the default point):

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=df1,aes(x=X1, y=Y1, color = groups1)) +
  geom_point(data=df2,aes(x=X2, y=Y2, fill = groups2), shape=21, color=NA) +
  scale_color_discrete("Pred") +
  scale_fill_discrete("Test")
```

which gives:

[image]

---

Another possibility is to use different linetypes for the different datasets:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=df1,aes(x=X1, y=Y1, color = groups1, linetype = "Pred")) +
  geom_line(data=df2,aes(x=X2, y=Y2, color = groups2, linetype = "Test")) +
  scale_color_discrete("Groups") +
  scale_linetype_discrete("Datasets")
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Actually, in the real datasets, the two `groups` variables have the same name, instead than `groups1` and `groups2` : I wasn't careful enough when creating the test case here (I didn't think it would matter!). Anyway, your second solution seems to work even in that case. I actually need to plot the points for the second dataset. I think that adding a `geom_point` layer should suffice...

Comment: whoa! Solution 1 now seems fantastic! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, ggplot makes one legend for one thing. You cannot have two color-legends.

You can use a different color for each main group and each subgroup by using interaction.

```
df1$group <- 1
df2$group <- 2


p <- ggplot() + geom_line(data=df1,aes(x=X1, y=Y1, color = interaction(group,groups1))) +
  geom_point(data=df2,aes(x=X2, y=Y2, color = interaction(group,groups2)))
p
```

[image]